# x:Bind to DependencyProperty not working (classic Binding works fine)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm having some problems porting my classic bindings to the new compiled bindings in a UWP app.

I have a UserControl with a simple `DependencyProperty`:

```
public double Value
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Value), typeof(double), typeof(MyUserControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(0d, OnValuePropertyChanged));

private static void OnValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the new value and do stuff on the control
}
```

In my page code-behind file I assign the DataContext and create a Parameter for the compiled binding:

```
public MyPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MyPageViewModel();
}

public MyPageViewModel ViewModel => (MyPageViewModel)DataContext;
```

Now, this classic binding **works** (the target Parameter has the INotifyPropertyChanged interface correctly implemented):

```
<controls:MyUserControl Value="{Binding MyValue}"/>
```

But this compiled binding **doesn't**:

```
<controls:MyUserControl Value="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyValue}"/>
```

The compiler doesn't give me an error, so it does find the target property when it builds the app, but at runtime it just doesn't work.

I guess I'm missing something really obvious and stupid here, but I just don't know what it is exactly. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most annoying difference between the "classic" Binding and the latest compiled binding (x:Bind) is the default binding mode. For classic Binding, the default is `OneWay` but for x:Bind the default is `OneTime`, so when you change the property value it doesn't reflect in the UI because the binding just picks up the value once and doesn't care for any future change notifications.

```
Value="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyValue, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Comment: That's exactly the kind of obvious and stupid thing I thought I could be missing ahahahahah Thank you!

Comment: This saved my day. How the default behaviour could be OneTime ? No need to bind something in this case, imo

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is if you're binding to a readonly property or to a property you're assigning from the viewmodel constructor